# Get Azure AD access token without client secret, username/password for Power BI from Angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, powerbi, access-token

Dears, My Angular app needs to get a access_token with `scope=https://analytics.windows.net/powerbi/api` Using this I need to fetch Power BI embed token. I cannot use username/password or client_secret. I can provide client_id/tenant_id, redirect_uri, I have looked at all the sof posts and read many documents in the net, but cannot figure it out. My app has redirect AAD login, but the access token has `scope=api://<some id> profile openid ...` Can I use implicit grant? Authorization code flow need interactive login, which is not possible. Can anyone help please? Any angular code sample/links to code will be great.

.....

More Details:

We are using "App-owns-data" approach. Logged in users will not have Power BI login access. We use security principal at Azure Side, and added power-bi-service API permission with report/dataset/dashboard read.all with the registered UI app.

Comment: See new answer.  TLDR you need an API (eg an Azure Function, or App Service App) to generate the embed token for "App-owns-data".

Comment: I have added more details in the post, apologies for not adding before, Can you please check them out and provide a solution? Really stuck here badly! Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

To embed from a browser app without a supporting back-end API, your users must be Power BI Pro Users (or Premium-Per-User) and you must use the "Embed For Your Organization" style of embedding.

There a sample in React and Typescript here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization

And here is the code that acquires the access token:

```
 msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest)
        .then((response: AuthResponse) => {

            // get access token from response: response.accessToken
            accessToken = response.accessToken;
            this.setUsername(response.account.name);
            this.getembedUrl();
        })
        .catch((err: AuthError) => {

            // refresh access token silently from cached id-token
            // makes the call to handleredirectcallback
            if (err.name === "InteractionRequiredAuthError") {
                msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(loginRequest);
            }
            else {
                thisObj.setState({ error: [err.toString()] })
            }
        });
```

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/React-TS/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData/src/App.tsx

Using this library: [UserAgentApplication](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal.useragentapplication.html#acquiretokensilent) to interact with AAD.

Because you fetch the access token with the user's identity, you can't use the "Application Owns Data" workflow.  That workflow requires a client secret or username/password.  Without a secure API to communicate with the Power BI service and generate the embed token, there's no way to securely use "Application Owns Data".  So you'll need a secured server API of some kind to hold the client secret and generate the embed token.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for responding. Actually, we are using "app-owns-data" / "embed-for-your-customer" approach. Please see the "More Details" section in the main question, where I have added more implementation details. Sorry for not adding those details before.

Comment: That won't work.  You need a secure back-end API for generating the embed token.  Technically you could use the API just for generating the Access Token, but that would be nearly just as insecure as sending the client secret or username/password to the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, creating a Azure function app or any other backend API is not an option right now. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Not securely, no.  There's no way to use "app-owns-data" / "embed-for-your-customer" without using a client secret or user/password to generate the Power BI access token, which is then used to generate the embed token.  There's no way to do that _securely_ without having a back-end API you can call to generate the embed token.

Comment: If you send the client secret to the browser, all users would have the same permissions as the embedding service principal. You wouldn't be able to securely restrict which reports and datasets they can use, or set the identity for row-level-security.